# Using a Pivot Table to run Overtime Analysis

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table, calculated-field

I am working on an overtime analysis report in which the data has been imported into Excel (2010).  I need to show overtime and time off hours only.  I've grouped all the time off hours by creating an additional column that only contains those hours (three different codes). Once the pivot tables are created, I'm creating line charts to show any correlation between time off and overtime in a department, month, and by person. It's working great for most of the employees, but . . .

The issue I'm having is that a segment of our employees have overtime built into their schedule, so the OT column values need to be reduced by that number.  (YTD built-in hours is 42).

I've created a calculated field to give me the adjusted OT hours.  The problem is when I create the chart, it includes all the fields - the time off data, the total overtime, and the adjusted overtime.  If I filter out the overtime, the table doesn't do the calculations for the adjusted overtime.  Is there a way to keep just the time off and adjusted overtime hours?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Calculations on detail records should not be done in a Pivot table. If - in your detail table - you create (or have) a field EmpClass that leads to another parameter table specifying the working hours per class, you can - via VLOOKUP and other functions - calculate the correct work/free/overtime for each record in the detail table and aggregate only these result fields.